# Environment variables in Typescript with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am having trouble declaring globals in Typescript, using Webpack's DefinePlugin. I was hoping to get some input on what I am doing wrong.

I created an environment variable in my `.bash_profile`:

```
export API_KEY_GOOGLE_MAPS=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In my webpack.config.js, I have the following lines:

```
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    API_KEY_GOOGLE_MAPS: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY_GOOGLE_MAPS),
  }),
],
...
```

Inside `index.tsx` (I am using React), I do the following:

```
declare var API_KEY_GOOGLE_MAPS: string;

console.log(API_KEY_GOOGLE_MAPS)
```

This produces the following error, at the line containing `console.log`:

```
ReferenceError: API_KEY_GOOGLE_MAPS is not defined
```

Does anybody have any leads?

Comment: I think you should configure ts-loader with transpileOnly flag, and compile it with babel

Comment: @ArtemSky This did not have any effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`create-react-app` environment variables should be prefixed with `REACT_APP_`:

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

from the "[Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)" documentation.

You should be adding these environment variables to your `.env` file(s) in place of adding these to your `.bash_profile` file. The appropriate file will be picked up depending on the build (i.e. `start` or `build`), and the application will be easier to share and deploy.

Comment: Thank you - I modified my solution to incorporate your feedback and that from Akyuna Akish.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers require `create-react-app` so I will offer mine.

First, add the plugin to your Webpack configuration:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  // ... 
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      MY_ENV_VAR: JSON.stringify(true),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Next, declare the variable in TypeScript:

```js
declare var MY_ENV_VAR : string | undefined;
```

Finally, you can access the variable in your code:

```js
console.log(MY_ENV_VAR);
```

Answer (score 5):

The way I do it is to have a .env file(add it to .gitignore) in the root of my project files.

Within that file I define my project environment variables(additional variables can be separated by adding each to it's own line):

```
NODE_ENV=development
```

Then using the dotenv npm module I can access the values in any webpack file(or server side expressJS file for example).

```
// in the command line
$ npm install --save dotenv

// at the top of the webpack config file
require('dotenv').config();

// in the plugins of the webpack config
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
],
```

Now I can reference it within my app being transpiled by webpack:

```
console.log(NODE_ENV); // development
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that .env files should be used for prod/sand/etc (e.g. `.env.prod`). builds as well and should not be added to .gitignore, only `.env` or `.env.local` files should be git-ignored.

Comment: I could see that, I usually deploy to Heroku which allows you to configure environment variables via the command line without a .env.prod file. Though with other hosting services I could see a .env.prod file coming in handy.

Comment: webpack is not defined, can be handled by adding `const webpack = require('webpack')` at the top of the webpack config file. However, NODE_ENV is still undefined in my app (TS2304: Cannot find name 'NODE_ENV'.)

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question: my project was generated using `create-react-app`, and according to its documentation, environment variables are accessed this way:

```
console.log(process.env.API_KEY_GOOGLE_MAPS)
```

`webpack.DefinePlugin()` is not required.